# Where does Play Framework store libraries?

Tags: maven, playframework, sbt, ivy, typesafe-activator

I am trying out the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/) 2.3.2 using the offline installation with [Typesafe Activator](https://typesafe.com/activator) 1.2.3 on Mac OS X 10.9.4.

In the `activator-1.2.3` folder I unzipped there is a `repository` folder that looks similar to my `~/.ivy2/cache` folder, in that it contains folders for... libraries? Bundles? I don't know the terminology.

Now, as far as my understanding goes, Activator uses SBT and SBT uses Ivy for dependency management. Ivy is *something like* Maven, it even uses its repositories.

My question are these:

- If I open a Play Framework project and Activator downloads all the dependencies, what is exactly happening?
- Is there a different process when I start building the project?
- Where do the libraries (bundles?) get downloaded to?
- Is `activator-1.2.3/repository` folder something like a bootstrap, and all the other dependencies go to `~/.ivy2`?
- What if I had Maven installed and there was a `~/.m2` folder?

So you see I am completely lost in this. Any insights are very much welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since 2.3.x [Play is distributed as an Activator distribution that contains all Play’s dependencies](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Highlights23) to follow sbt's rules, i.e. dependencies/libraries built locally go to `~/.ivy2/local` while the cache of downloaded dependencies/libraries is under `~/.ivy2/cache`.

And later in the [What’s new in Play 2.3](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Highlights23) document:

> Default ivy cache and local repository
>
> Play now uses the default ivy
>   cache and repository, in the .ivy2 folder in the users home directory.
>
> This means Play will now integrate better with other sbt builds, not
>   requiring artifacts to be cached multiple times, and allowing the
>   sharing of locally published artifacts.

When you `update` (and hence `compile` or `run`) a Play 2.3.x project, the dependencies go to `~/.ivy2/cache`.

What's under `activator-1.2.3/repository` appears a local Ivy2 repository to speed up resolving dependencies that otherwise would've been downloaded from online repositories.

Dependencies under `~/.m2` have to be added explicitly as described in [Library dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html) and [Resolvers](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Resolvers.html) in the official documentation of sbt.

You may find `fullResolvers` task useful to learn about the available resolvers/repositories.

```
[jacoco4sbt-play] $ help fullResolvers
Combines the project resolver, default resolvers, and user-defined resolvers.
[jacoco4sbt-play] $ show fullResolvers
[info] ArrayBuffer(Raw(ProjectResolver(inter-project, mapped: )), FileRepository(local,FileConfiguration(true,None),Patterns(ivyPatterns=List(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), artifactPatterns=List(${ivy.home}/local/[organisation]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]), isMavenCompatible=false, descriptorOptional=false, skipConsistencyCheck=false)), public: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, Typesafe Releases Repository: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Sep 23, 2014 11:02:19 PM
```

Comment: I downloaded the offline distribution which is about 350 MB and includes a repository folder for all required JAR files but after entering the RUN command it tries to DOWNLOAD (!!!) all dependencies again via Ivy and Maven! Why?!

Comment: Use gist.github.com to show the commands you're executing and their results. Paste the link here.